# Java Regex Troubles

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string that needs to be extracted using regex. It’s preferable that only a single regex is used. As it’s used in a loop with 9 pre-existing Regex’s.(Ie, so i can just add it to the ArrayList of available regex's)

The pattern of strings will always be 
Between {4,8} A-Z0-9. Followed by either,
[A-Z]{1} or [A-Z0-9]{2} or, another [A-Z0-9]{4,8}

For example:

```
“A1B1C1 ABCD E FGHI JK X0Y0Z0”
```

I’d want this to return four matches.

```
A1B1C1 & ABCD E & FGHI JK & X0Y0Z0
```

I've been trying to match the first part of {4,8} chatactures, followed by a non-greedy match for {1,2}. For example(s):

```
[A-Z0-9]{4,8}(\\s{1}[A-Z0-9]{1,2})*?   &&   [A-Z0-9]{4,8}(\\s{1}[A-Z]{1}|\\s{1}[A-Z0-9]{2})*?
```

But this never returns more than the first {4,8} charactures.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? Perhaps you should have included your original failing regex.

Comment: @plalx The question is updated with the tried patterns. I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an optional part with a word boundary and an alternation to match either `[A-Z0-9]{2}` or `[A-Z]`

```
\b[A-Z0-9]{4,8}(?:\h+(?:[A-Z0-9]{2}|[A-Z]))?\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-Z0-9]{4,8}` Match 4 - 8 times A-Z0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `(?:[A-Z0-9]{2}|[A-Z])` Match either 2 x A-Z0-9 or 1 x A-Z
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aoRFlr/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/zos41d)

In Java

```
String regex = "\\b[A-Z0-9]{4,8}(?:\\h+(?:[A-Z0-9]{2}|[A-Z]))?\\b";
```

Comment: The Fourth Bird,   This answer is 100%, I appreciate it very much,  didn’t know Non Capture a group’s existed, you’ve given me the next thing I should learn about.   Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JamesHudson You are welcome. Could you add your initial regex to the question?

Comment: I'veadded the initial Regex's tothe question.